# How do I add double quotes to a query I'm sending from R to Redshift

Tags: r, postgresql, odbc

I have a `odbc` connection from R to Redshift and this is my query

```
select
   "timestamp"
from table
where ds > '2020-01-01'
```

Timestamp is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, and so I wrap it in quotes to indicate that I want the column, not the reserved word. And, I wrap the date in single quotes because I think that's what I'm supposed to do for dates.

My challenge is that I don't know how to accomplish both with R

This is currently my code

```
query <-
"select
   timestamp
from table
where ds > '2020-01-01'"

send_query(query)
```

The send query command simply uses `odbc` to send the query to my database

The problem is that it gives me an error since timestamp is a reserved word

Comment: Nope, because the SQL query fails when the date is wrapped in double quotes

Comment: How about `query <-"select \"timestamp\" from table where ds > '2020-01-01'"`

Comment: It keeps the `\` in my output. What if I did that and then used `gsub` to get rid of the slashes

Comment: You might try: `select quote_ident('timestamp');   "timestamp"`

Comment: I tried `  str_replace_all(query, "\\", "")` and it said this `Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)`

Comment: @Cauder the slashes aren't "really" there. They are escape characters that mean "the following is an actual quote, not the end of the string". If you `cat(query)` you will see that the backslash magically disappers when strings are not quoted. You can't regex out the backslashes because they _aren't there_

Comment: Oh sweet, let me try sending that query over

Comment: What query worked?

Comment: I added backslashes and sent that query, which makes sense since they're not really there

Comment: @AllanCameron, can you please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
query <-"select \"timestamp\" from table where ds > '2020-01-01'"
```

The backslashes aren't "really" there. They are simply escape characters that indicate that you intend a literal double quote rather than the end of the string.